# Read cookies inside a static method

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, static, static-methods

I have problem with reading cookies inside a static method. 
I tried:

```
static void Method()
{
    Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
         HttpCookie reader= page.Request.Cookies["myCookie"];
}
```

but I think it doesn't work.

Do you have any ideas how can I do this?

Comment: Why do you think that it doesn't work? Please provide more details.

Comment: Maybe I've made a mistake but I see that this "cookies reader" can't read cookies :)

Comment: Have you set any cookies in your application? You will only see cookies from the current domain, not other cookies that are stored in the browser.

Comment: of course I did but i think i have to check my code one more time.

Answer (score 5):

Please read the documentation on msdn regarding cookies in asp.net [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.ASPX)
My guess is that you don't need the Handler in order to read the cookies. See what [HttpContext.Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.handler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is.

I recommend you to try out:

```
static void Method()
{
    HttpCookie reader = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["myCookie"];
}
```